# How to print files in a directory without extension? PYTHON

Tags: python, operating-system

I iterated through my directory using os.listdir() and I have some files that have extensions and some do not. How do I search within the directory to find and list all of the files that do not have an extension. I'm not trying to list all of them, just the ones that don't have a .pub extension?

Comment: So you can check using ```if not what_ever.endswith('.pub')```

Comment: you can just filter out paths that don't have a `.pub` substring

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('YourDirectoryPath/*[!.pub]')
```

Here's [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) in python documenttion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a list of strings named `files`, where each string is a file path, then if you are looking for the ones that aren't `.pub` you can check to see if string does not include `.pub` and print it out, such as:

```py
for file in files:
  if ".pub" not in file:
    print(file)
```

Out of curiosity if you are using Linux you can easily do so by using bash with some standard utilities, for example:

```sh
find -type f -name '*.pub' > non-pub.txt
```

Step by step we have:

- Using `find` which is available in most if not all Linux based distributions;
- `-type f` will search only for files, not directories;
- `-name '*.pub'` will tell us out of those files which ones end in `.pub`;
- `> non-pub.txt` will send the results to a file named `non-pub.txt`.

You can use this from within Python using the `os` module. For example if you really want to keep it in a file and not do anything with it, then the usage of `os.system()` will do:

```py
os.system("find -type f -name '*.pub'")
```

Or if instead you want to keep the output and manipulate the results in Python:

```py
files = os.popen("find -type f -name '*.pub'").read().split("\n")[0:-1]
```

This will not work if you have files with newlines `\n` as file names, but that's something that I've never seen happening before.